# How do I filter on eagerly-loaded tables in Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

Basically, I want to be able to retrieve users and eagerly load e-mail addresses, and then restrict which users I bring in with a where clause.

```
$query = User::with('emails')->whereIn ('user_id', $user_ids);

$query->where('emails.email_address', 'LIKE', "%example%");

$usersWithEmails = $query->get();
```

This works:

```
$query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%test%");
```

which leads me to believe that the where clause is only being applied to the base user object, but I don't want to get users who don't match that e-mail. I'm aware that I can do this with several queries, but this is for a UI filter and they can filter on many child tables, so this would work much better).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to filter users based on a relationship, what you are looking for is `whereHas`.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

```
User::whereIn('id', [1, 3])->whereHas('emails', function ($query) {
  $query->where('emails.email_address', 'LIKE', '%example%');
})->with('emails');
```

This will: select users with id = [1,3], Then filter out the results where the email pattern is not matched and then will load the relationship for the resulting rows.

The difference about using `whereHas` and `with` (**Logan's** example) is that the latter will load all users but email field **WILL BE NULL** for these where the eager loading pattern is not matched.

Of course you can accomplish the same using eager loading restrictions and then filtering the collection by null fields, but I find this cleaner. I let the DB do the job for me =)

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. Logan Bailey's answer works, but I have many filters that I may or may not want to add, and putting them all into the with clause was impractical. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can change the with parameter into an associative array, where the key is the name of the relationship and the value is a closure that applies any related constraints.

```
$query = User::with(['emails' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('emails.email_address', 'LIKE', '%example%');
}])->whereIn ('user_id', $user_ids);
```

You can see [Eloquent's docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) for more information, it's the first bullet point in "Eager Loading".